# Is there a way to initialize a React state via a promise?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, promise, es6-promise, use-state

Is it possible to initialise my component's state via a promise's resolved value? I wish to retrieve a value via a server API call and use it as my initial state value. Something along the lines of:

```js
const http = axios.create({
  baseURL: window.location.origin,
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
  },
});

const App = () => {
  const [dataSize, setDataSize] = useState<number>(() => (
    http.get('/api/getDataCount')
      .then(({ data }) => {
        return data.count;
      })
      .catch(() => {
        return 0;
      })
  ));
  // ...
};
```

I know the above code won't work, because what is returned is actually a promise, but that's the gist of what I'm trying to achieve. The following code should work, however:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [dataSize, setDataSize] = useState<number>(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    http.get('/api/getDataCount')
      .then(({ data }) => setDataSize(data.count));
  }, []);
```

Is there a better way than the above, though? How can I directly access the promise's returned value and initialise the state with it, without assigning a placeholder value I'll never use?

Comment: You could call `setDataSize` once you get the data, and show a loading state in your component until you get it, or you could hoist the data fetching to a parent component and not render your child until you have it. React "suspense" also handles cases like this https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactsuspense

Comment: unfortunately no, your last code block is correct.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial so there's no better way than that?

Comment: I don't think there is a better way than that. Besides the existence of a default/placeholder value allows you to display a placeholder/skeleton component before the data is fetched.

Comment: @thegreatjedi not in react, no.